# How can I match a bunch of p tags at the end of an html document with javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a sample content:

```
<p> so so so </p>
<div> whatever</div
<p> another paragraph </p>
<div> forever </div>
<p> first of last </p>
<p> second of last </p>
```

How can I match the last two paragraphs (or any number of consecutive paragraphs) at the end of the above document?

The match output I want is:

```
<p> first of last </p>
<p> second of last </p>
```

I tried `/(<p>[\s\S]*?<\/p>[\s]*)$/g`, but the lazy matching is not working as expected, it sucks all the p tags in between, and matches from the first opening p tag it encounters up to the end of the document.

Note: there might not be paragraphs at the end at all, the regex should not match if there are no paragraphs at the end.

Comment: Please update your question with code that you have tried and be more specific about the issue you are having with your code.

Comment: updated, is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

Here we use regex to match all paragraphs and then take the last two elements of the result array.

```js
let str = `<p> so so so </p>
<div>
whatever
</div
<p> another paragraph </p>
<div> forever </div>
<p> first of last </p>
<p> second of last </p>`

let reg = /<p>[\w\s]*<\/p>/g;

let res = str.match(reg);

console.log(res[res.length-2]);
console.log(res[res.length-1]);
```

Comment: How can I use that if I have not just 2 but 3 or 4 paragraphs at the end? I have no way of knowing how many paragraphs there will be at the end of the document.

Comment: And another thing is the paragraphs have to be at the end of the document, and there can't be another tag between them. Your approach doesn't guarantee that.

Comment: why? my approach only matches the <p> tags it doesn't matter if other tags between them.

Comment: @faint-hearted-fool but when you check for a specific amount of tags at the end of the document then you have to know before how many there are or not? In my approach to just get all tags you could use a loop and just take the last X elements for example and this will lead in the end in the same result.

Comment: the regex is also meant to detect if there are paragraphs at the end at all, your approach assumes that there are paragraphs at the end, but there might not be.

Comment: ah well now I understand. Yes that's right but you could easily bypass it by checking if res  has elements but I understand your concerns

Answer (score 0):

Adding a negative look ahead to make sure nested paragraphs are not matched seems to do the trick:

`/(<p>((?!<p>)[\s\S])*?<\/p>[\s]*)+$/g`

Would appreciate better suggestions though!

Comment: have you tested it?

Comment: yes, it seems to work, but for some reason it doesn't feel clean.

Comment: I am asking because I took it into my snippet and checked against your string and it just give the last element as result `[
  "<p> second of last </p>"
]`

Comment: sorry, add + at the end before $, forgot to include that